# always failure when get Response from API retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

this is my APIservice class (endpoint API calling class)

```
public interface WeatherService {
@GET("{latitude},{longitude}")
Call<Weather> getWeather(@Path("latitude") double d, @Path("longitude") double d2); }
```

this is my network request call

```
public class RetroCLient {
private static final String ROOT_URL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/api_id/";
private static Retrofit getRetrovitInstance() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static WeatherService getApiService() {
    return getRetrovitInstance().create(WeatherService.class);
} }
```

get response from server

```
                            getLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                final ProgressDialog dialog;
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.string_getting_json_title));
                dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.string_getting_json_message));
                dialog.show();

                WeatherService api = RetroCLient.getApiService();
                Call<Weather> call = api.getWeather(getLat(),getLon());

                /**
                 * Enqueue Callback will be call when get response...
                 */
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Weather>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Weather> call, Response<Weather> response) {
                        //Dismiss Dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                            /**
                             *
                             * Got Successfully
                             */
                            dailylist = (ArrayList<Datum__>) response.body().getDaily().getData();

                            /**
                             * Binding that List to Adapter
                             */
                            adapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, dailylist);
                            rowdata.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } else {
                            Snackbar.make(parentview, R.string.string_some_thing_wrong, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Weather> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("shit","shit");
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Snackbar.make(parentview, R.string.string_internet_connection_not_available, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

but when i try to run the app, i didnt get the data from the server..
whats wrong? :((

please help me....

Comment: In on failure method  type Log.d("failure",t.getMessage()+"");  , check what  you got and post it .

Comment: are you providing the call with  api key ?